# Android:cannot run my app

Tags: android, android-studio

this error appears to me

```
 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dummy.dummy-1/lib/arm64
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17472 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: That's not an error. It should be in red.  Copy that. And where's your code? We're not magicians.

Comment: i new to android and android studio , what code do you need so i can edit the post for you